# Are there any performance differences between `SELECT` and `FROM` in subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, derived-table

These queries return the same result, which is better performance?

#### Subquery in SELECT

```
SELECT
    books.id,
    books.title,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscriptions WHERE books.id = subscriptions.book_id) AS subscription_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books) AS book_count
FROM books
ORDER BY id;
```

#### Subquery in FROM

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        books.id,
        books.title,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscriptions WHERE books.id = subscriptions.book_id) AS subscription_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books) AS book_count
    FROM books) AS tmp
ORDER BY id;
```

And I should get `book_count` from other sql in this case?

Comment: Why don't you compare query plans and see if there is any difference?

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is called a derived table and for modern DBMS there is no performance difference whatsoever. So

```
select * 
from some_table
order by some_column;
```

will have *exactly* the same performance as:

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from some_table
) t
order by some_column;
```

Comment: I'm using latest MySQL. Thanks!